# Artificial Intelligence : How to route sentence to action

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, gate

I'm a beginner in the field of artificial intelligence... I can use GATE or any other Natural Language Processing but I don't have an answer for this :

Do you know how to evaluate how 2 sentences can be close? even with a large data set?

Do you have any recommendations? I can use the number of permutation, the lengh, the number of tokens, metaphone them, etc... but I don't know what test I should use.

My goal is :
    - "Hello Jarvis"
    - "Hello Romain, how are you"

```
- "Hello arvis"
- "Hello Romain, how are you"

- "Hello mister Swift"
- I don't know what you are expecting, is this like "Hello Jarvis" ?
- Yes
- Ok, Hello Romain, How are you?

- "Hello mister swift, how are you?"
- I don't know what are you expecting.
```

## Exemple

By 1, 2, 3 or n is just an example of similarity scale.

### Basic

```
- "Hello IA" is closed to
   - "Hello IA" by 0
   - "Hello AI" by 1 

- "Hello Jarvis" is closed to 
   - "Hello AI" by 2 
   - "Hello IA" by 2

- "Hello! mister Swift" is closed to
   - "Hello AI" by 3
   - "Hello IA" by 3
   - "Hello Jarvis" by 2
```

### Less Basic

```
- "Hello IA" is (token length, token word, grammatically, syntactically) closed to
   - "Hello IA" by (0,0,0,0)
   - "Hello AI" by (0,1,0,0) 

- "Hello Jarvis" is closed to 
   - "Hello AI" by (0,2,1,1) 
   - "Hello IA" by (0,2,1,1)

- "Hello! mister Swift" is closed to
   - "Hello AI" by (1,2,2,2)
   - "Hello IA" by (1,2,2,2)
   - "Hello Jarvis" by (1,2,2,2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ready to learn hard-core NLP, you may use a *classifier* for this task. Have a look for instance at [Stanford NLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/) (Java) or [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) (Python).

If you want to keep things simple and use an out-of-the-box solution, have a look at the [Wit.ai API](https://wit.ai) it does exactly what you need, and more.

Comment: hard-core <3
I check Wit, it's really good but my project need to work without internet. Anyway, it's just a little part (human input) of a personal project so I can learn. **My problem is really "what to use?" and "how to combine?"**

I found [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/semantics/) but it's just for semantic means (classifier4j) and I think it's not really appropriate for a large set of data.

ps : I have a look to the stanford NLP, I think I will include it, great lib.

Answer (score 0):

One way to determine string similarity is to use String kernels. There's a good paper by Lodhi et al explaining how this works:

http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/LodhiSSCW02.pdf

In order to create a classifier using CoreNLP you would have to create features for the string, such as n-grams, lemmas or similar.